# How to disable/hide the close button of firefox browser using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to disable or hide the close button that we get on the top right side of the firefox browser. Please help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not possible without an extension (and even then, I'm not sure if an extension can).

Answer (score 2):

How about just don't do that.  Nobody wants you to do that.  If it is a requirement for your project, you need to tell whoever wrote the spec that you're not going to do that because it violates basic UI guidelines and they need to come up with a better solution.  Also, you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Basic browser interface is outside a page's boundaries. Only the user can hide it/remove it

That sounds like what a malicious software would accomplish. So no, you can't do it. It would require an exploit or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because the browser's interface is not part of the web page.

An ASP.Net application is a server side application; when the user requests a page, your application which is located on the server responds, and generates HTML code, that it sends back to the client who requested that page.

Only JavaScript executes on client side.